# ng-cordova geolocation plugin doesn't show gps icon in notification bar

Tags: android, geolocation, ionic-framework, ngcordova

i am using  ng-cordova geolocation plugin
all functionality work fine except problem to display gps symbol in notification bar.

any solution for display gps symbol in notification bar when user enable gps button from mobile device?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how to display gps symbol like when we are using google map in our mobile devices google provide gps symbol in notification bar when gps is enable of your mobile device.

Comment: http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gps-status-calibration.jpg                                                                                                this is example of my question to display gps icon [top left corner].

Comment: so if you simply use get location then it normally wont show up, if you use watch location it will, or at least it will on android. That is my experience with it so far

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ng-cordova geolocation plugin, simply switch on the gps location. 
then gps signal should automatically appear in the notification bar. 
This is standard android OS. 
Only in case you have a different launcher installed,it may not show it, thats the launcher issue, they may not update it in real time.

If your ng-cordova geolocation plugin, doesn't switch gps on then you need to invoke following android code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.map_dialog_title));
            dialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.map_dialog_msg));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.menu_settings),
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                             context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel),
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: This is quite an answer but in my case the GPS icon does not show in certain devices. In other devices, it shows fine. Showing the icon or not, the geolocation is found.